# run runOnUiThread() repeatedly causes exception

Tags: android, android-runonuithread

(2016.3.15 Updated)

I encountered a strange problem last week and I'd like to discuss this with you.

Problem Scenarios：

There's a searchView in a AppCompatActivity. Whenever the text changed, the fragment within the Activity will be replaced through "`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment).commit();`".

In the fragment, there's a thread called SearchThread,which will be executed in the `onActivityCreated()`. Getting to the point, there's a `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable{...})`method in it. No matter what is in the "new Runnable()", a NullPointerException will occur when the text of searchView changes quickly, which results in the frequent reestablishment of this fragment.

**Logcat**:

```
03-15 20:12:25.912/cn.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10820  
   Process: cn.example.app, PID: 31532  
   java.lang.NullPointerException  
       at cn.example.app.homepage.GymFragment$searchThread.run(GymFragment.java:257)  
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

But, if I use sendMessage(searchHandler.obtain...) instead of runOnUiThread, everything will go well!!

**GymFragment.Java**：

```
@Override  
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){  
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    new Thread(new SearchThread()).start();  
}  
class SearchThread implements Runnable{  
        @Override  
        public void run() {  
        String s = "";  
            try {  
                Thread.sleep(4000);  
            } catch (Exception e) {;}  
            //searchHandler.sendMessage(searchHandler.obtainMessage(0, s));//Correct   
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { //Throw NullPointer Exception or pool-1-thread-1 (with ExecutorService) 
                @Override  
                public void run() {  
                    ;  
                }  
            });  
        }  
}
```

**SearchActivity.Java**:

```
class queryChangeListener implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        currentSearchTip = newText;
        if (newText != null && newText.length() > 0) {
            searchDelayed(newText);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
private Handler searchHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg == null)
            return;
        String searchText = (String) msg.obj;
        if (currentSearchTip != null && currentSearchTip.isEmpty()==false) {
            GymFragment fragment = GymFragment.newInstance(searchText);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
};
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
private String currentSearchTip;
public void searchDelayed(String newText) {
    scheduledExecutor.schedule(new SearchThread(newText),500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
class SearchThread implements Runnable {
    String newText;
    public SearchThread(String newText){
        this.newText = newText;
    }
    public void run() {
        if (newText != null && newText.equals(currentSearchTip)) {
            searchHandler.sendMessage(searchHandler.obtainMessage(0, newText));
        }
    }
}
```

**Solutions**：

1) Comment out"getActivity()..."，use the commented "sendMessage(searchhandler.obtain..)" instead.

2) Before run getActivity().runOnUiThread(), judge getActivity()==null first.

---

2016.3.14:

*[ Some things interesting:) ]*

1. the source code of "runOnUiThread"

runOnUIThread(Runnable r)'s source code：

```
public final void runOnUiThread(Runnable action) {  
        if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {  
            mHandler.post(action);  
        } else {  
            action.run();  
        }  
}
```

In fact,runOnUiThread calls mHandler.post(Runnable r).

Let's see what's in post(Runnable r):

```
public final boolean post(Runnable r)  {    
       return  sendMessageDelayed(getPostMessage(r), 0);    
}
```

And in the getPostMessage(Runnable r)：

```
private final Message getPostMessage(Runnable r) {    
        Message m = Message.obtain();    
        m.callback = r;    
        return m;    
}
```

Then in the Message.obtain()：

```
public final Message obtainMessage()  {    
      return Message.obtain(this);    
}

public static Message obtain(Message orig) {    
       Message m = obtain();    
       m.what = orig.what;    
       m.arg1 = orig.arg1;    
       m.arg2 = orig.arg2;    
       m.obj = orig.obj;    
       m.replyTo = orig.replyTo;    
       if (orig.data != null) {    
           m.data = new Bundle(orig.data);    
       }    
       m.target = orig.target;    
       m.callback = orig.callback;    

       return m;    
}  

/**   
     * Return a new Message instance from the global pool. Allows us to   
     * avoid allocating new objects in many cases.   
     */    
public static Message obtain() {    
      synchronized (sPoolSync) {    
            if (sPool != null) {    
                Message m = sPool;    
                sPool = m.next;    
                m.next = null;    
                sPoolSize--;    
                return m;    
            }    
      }    
      return new Message();  
 }
```

2.the Source Code of "sendMessage(Message msg)"：

```
public final boolean sendMessage(Message msg)  {    
       return sendMessageDelayed(msg, 0);    
}
```

Here we can see，the implementation of sendMessage(Message msg) is almost equal to the one of post(Runnable r). The difference may be associated with getPostMessage(Runnable r).

So, briefly, what actually results in the correct execution of 
searchHandler.SendMessage(searchHandler.obtainMessage(0,str)), 
while results in the exception of getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable{...}), when I simultaneously executed them repeatedly?
Thanks very much!

Comment: You said a null pointer exception occurs. But you didn't supply the actual log showing the exception. That's the most crucial piece of information. I'm thinking probably your getActivity is what's returning null. You should make sure to pass a suitable context to the worker thread, e.g. by passing a final Activity rather than calling getActivity from the thread, because the activity's lifecycle may have ended. You might also want to check activity.isFinishing when the thread is done.

Comment: @JHH Thanks!!!I have edited my description and put logcat on it.You are right, the problem is that getActivity returned null.But I don't know why,because the fragment is always inside that Activity.

Comment: Are you trying to perform something like instant search or search suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure why your fragment is detached from the activity. But if you want to run that code regardless of your application state, you could simply use a Handler instead of runOnUiThread. Just make sure to create the Handler in the ui/main thread and all calls to post() will result in the Runnable running on the ui/main thread.